# OutOfMemory Exception Android VectorBitmap

Tags: android, android-activity, out-of-memory, android-vectordrawable

I'm using vectordrawable for displaying images. The images are all resources which are bundled with the app (apk). My problem is, that the memory on every new activity massivly get higher until the app crashes with an OutOffMemoryException.

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:903)
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:880)
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:847)
```

I've looked into MAT for memory leaks, but did'nt find out any more than the bitmap errors.

What are the efficients way to display vectordrawables? Maybe the general architecture of my app isnt right with the activity lifecycle?

I didn't find any informations about the common memory ussage of other apps (facebook, aibnb, whatsapp,..). My usage is around 40-70MB.

Comment: Can you add something describing the general architecture of your app, and how you transition between activities?

Comment: the transition is made with intents, "startActivity". like described here http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

the general architecture is made with an abstract base class, for all common functions / properties. all other should be normal and standard.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things to be careful about when dealing with images:

1. Are you loading your images every time when you show them? This can be a potentially very memory consuming operation. It's better to load the images into memory once and then reuse them across the app.
2. Are you cleaning the memory occupied by the images you no longer use? If you are sure that an image is no longer needed, you should clean the allocated bitmap memory by calling `bitmap.recycle()`. This invalidates the bitmap and frees all the occupied memory, making it available for other operations.
3. Are the images too large? There is a limit for the maximum size of a single image. Trying to load a bigger image will also cause an `OutOfMemoryError`, even though memory can be available. In that case, you may want to optimise the image files that you are trying to load.

Go though your app and check for those potential problems one by one. Also, there are good profiling tools available for the Android platform. They can show you potential problems with the memory management, like excessive memory allocation, etc.

Good luck.

Comment: 1. what do you mean by loading? I've declared the most images in the xml layout. Or in many cases with "setImageResource". I saw alredy few posts about caching. Maybe this is a thing I have to check out.

2. This would be hard. If there are many images, I have to do this for every image. Maybe I have to declare an array of ID's? Whats about resuming? Destroying does recycle the image memory? So the flow will be, setting to cache on create / resume. And recycle on pause, destroy?

3. The imagefiles doesnt have any sizes because they are vectordrwables (XML/SVG).

Comment: I was thinking you are loading the images yourself and doing some drawing. If you are using them the way you do, you should try and investigate what causes those bitmap creations and if, indeed, this is the major problem. As to point 2, in your case this should be managed by the Android platform. 3. I was talking about memory size, not just width and height.